# Hair Particle Disk Cache gets cleared after reopening the file

Tags: particles, hair, cache

When I bake my hair simulation I use the disk cache option to cache my simulation in a separate folder. Like described in the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/physics/baking.html).

When I start the bake, I can watch how the cache files get distributed into the "blendcache_FILENAME" folder. However, when I save and close the file and reopen it, Blender clears the cache automatically and does not just read the cache as I was expecting.